# why is stop-loss and take-profit not working?

Tags: pine-script

I am pretty new to pinescript. Although my code runs, changing the values of my stop loss percent and take profit percent does not have any bearing on the outcome. while examining the outcome of a backtest, my losses in trades exceed the stop loss percent. any insight would be helpful, as I am at a loss.

```
//@version=4

//define the strategy
strategy("Long-Only Momentum Strategy")

//set the lookback period
lookback = 365

//calculate the momentum
momentum = close - close[lookback]

//calculate the RSI
rsiValue = rsi(close, 14)

//set the entry rule
entry = momentum > 0 and rsiValue < 80

//set the stop loss percentage
stopLossPercent = 2

//set the take profit percentage
takeProfitPercent = 5

//calculate the stop loss price
stopLossPrice = close * (1 - stopLossPercent/100)

//calculate the take profit price
takeProfitPrice = close * (1 + takeProfitPercent/100)

//enter a long position when the entry rule is triggered
if entry
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

//exit the long position when the stop loss is triggered
if close < stopLossPrice
strategy.close("Long")

//exit the long position when the take profit is triggered
if close > takeProfitPrice
strategy.close("Long")

//exit the long position when the exit rule is triggered
if close < sma(close,200)
strategy.close("Long")
```

I tried rewriting the stoploss and take profit various ways, with the same result

Comment: The generated code is full of basic error. Is it a chatGPT generated code ?

Comment: Like I said, I am new to pinescript. Your response also has “basic error(s)” - I’m guessing you don’t have any insight on how to fix my stop loss, but thanks for your lack of help

Comment: Example of basic errors : you don't respect the indentation of the 'if' block. Please post a code without error, this way we will be able to reproduce the behaviour and propose you some fix.